# Changing language with a redirect_to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to change the param language in my web when the users write www.myweb.com/en-GB/ , and the default language is es-ES.

I'm redirecting like this:

```
params[:language] = session[:language]

redirect_to params
```

It's working fine with all my routes except one and I don't know why.

When i try to redirect with this params:

```
{:action=> "index" ,:controller=>"bt/contact_center", :language=>"es-ES"}
```

I used Engine on my program. When I try to redirect to a route without main_app, I get an error like this:

```
*** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method contact_center_index_path' for #<Bt::ContactCenterController:0x007f98338f7348>
```

If I use main_app.route it works fine:

```
(rdb:1) main_app.contact_center_index_path
"http://localhost:3000/es-ES/contact_center"
```

When I try to use  `redirect_to params` , program is calling  contact_center_index_path instead of main_app.contact_center_index_path and I don't know how fix it.

I need to do something like:

```
reditect_to main_app(params) or redirect_to main_app.controller_name_path(params)
```

This are my  definition routes:

```
mount Bt::Engine => '/'
  scope '/:language' do 
     resources :contact_center, controller: "bt/contact_center", :only => [:index] do
        collection do 
          post :createinc
        end
    end
 end
end
```

Rake routes:

```
    createinc_contact_center_index POST /:language/contact_center/createinc(.:format)                 bt/contact_center#upload_fax
    contact_center_index GET  /:language/contact_center(.:format)                            bt/contact_center#index
```

Comment: The `:action=> index` should be `:action=> "index"` isn't it?